# Add Custom url to href in email template not working

Tags: magento2, url, email-templates

I try to generate an `a href` element in my email template that will open a mobile app, to do this i just have to replace the http or https in url with my app name, the `a href` element should contain the url like this:

```
//var url = 'test://test.com';
<a href={{var url}} target="__blank"> Test </a>
```

if i use the Deeplinking url like above code, the `href` of `a` element wont show in my email, so the `a href` element become unclickable

```
<a target="__blank"> Test </a>
```

but if i use normal url it works just fine

```
//var url = 'http://test.com';
<a href={{var url}} target="__blank"> Test </a>
```